# quarkus: startup time is 2 times slower than documented

Tags: quarkus

I used the **getting-started**-project from the quarkus quickstart and compiled it. I started it with `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`. **However, it starts after about 1.495s.** In the documentation it is reached in about 0.668s. So in my case it is about **2 times slower than** documented in the quarkus website. Btw, I restarted it a few times to check if it will be faster without changing/compiling any file. However, it starts always about 1.495s. Why the big difference?

```
[INFO] ----------------------< org.acme:getting-started >----------------------
[INFO] Building getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Final:dev (default-cli) @ getting-started ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
2019-11-27 13:11:13,904 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.0.0.Final started in 1.495s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2019-11-27 13:11:13,923 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2019-11-27 13:11:13,924 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy]
```

**My machine:** JDK 12 / MacBook 2018 / RAM: 16GB

*I already set my hosts file by https://thoeni.io/post/macos-sierra-java/.*

Comment: How does the startup time compare if you running with "java -jar"?

I don't believe the documented startup time is based on "quarkus:dev"

Comment: `quarkus:dev` does a bunch of things that make the initial launch slower than `java -jar`

Comment: And also, it really depends on the machine. Perhaps your machine is 2 times slower than then test machine?

Comment: I did a run with `java -jar getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar` and the startup time is **0.854s**. So I think, this is okay. According to https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started under section 5, it uses `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` and it starts (according to its logs) in **0.668s.**. I dont reach this with my machine even with a `java -jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methodology for start times shown on the website is documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/performance-measure#how-do-we-measure-startup-time. It is important to note that the advertised start time measurements are from starting the application to processing the first request. First request time is not represented in the Info log message.

There are a large number of factors that influence the absolute start times observed, including (but not limited to) platform O/S, CPU specification, Java version, GC implementation, power management, hostname resolution etc.

It is unlikely that you will observe the same absolute start times, it is also possible to observe better start times than have been measured on our lab environment.

What is important to note in the start times displayed on the home page of the website is the difference between startup times for different deployment scenarios; more importantly the relative speed up from other frameworks.